# Plan Date /Actual Date

Tags: excel

How to do this in Excel? What will be the code??

If `Plan Date (P)` is less than `Today` it Turns into `Red`
If `Plan Date (P)` is `Next day` it Turns into `Orange`
If `Plan Date (P)` greater than `Today` Do Noting
If any `Actual Date (A)` is input then `Plan Date (P)` Turns into `Green`

[image: enter image description here]]

Plan/Actual

[image: Plan/Actual]

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting:

Based on your example assuming top left is cell A1. CTRL + Select B1:D1 & B3:D3, click conditional formatting and new rule. Click "use a formula to determine cells to format" at the bottom of the list and enter the following formulas to the selected range:

`=B1<Today()-1` & format to fill red & bold font

`=B1=Today()-1` & format to fill orange & bold font

`=B2<>""` and format to fill green & white bold font

Use new rule for each formula. Adjust ranges to meet your needs.

Note: Conditional formatting will evaluate condition top to bottom, so if cell meets multiple conditions (ex: date is less than today and actual date is entered) the highest conditional formatting rule will be applied. So make sure your green fill format is at the top.

Comment: No it is not work as what I needed... This is for a work schedule. If work is late then it is Showing Red if work is on upcoming date is is showing Nothing.. and if work date is next day it will be Orange. 
and if any actual work date (Actual Work Date means work is done) is given it will turn in Green cz it is done. 
and I have to do this for 500 row and 100 column

Comment: This does exactly what you described in both your original question and this last comment. Make sure you are selecting your entire range (only the cells you want formatted, not the input cells) when you select the range to apply the conditional formatting. If you still have problems, select one of the cells in the range you have applied the conditional formatting to, click conditional formatting, and click manage rules. Take and post a screenshot so I can see if it's set up correctly.